# Unique key violada quando estou fazendo um delete. Por quê?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, oracle10g

Estou com um problema que parece ser bobo mas estou patinando e não consigo resolver. Tenho uma aplicação legal feita em Java usando JPA 2 com Spring, Spring Data, JSF, etc... Ela funciona muito bem. A base que estou usando é Oracle 10g.

Bem agora vem o problema, tenho duas tabelas. Uma relacionada com a outra. Da seguinte forma:

```
Tabela: aplicacoes

 - id (pk);
 - nome;
 - usuario_acesso (unique key);
 - password;

Tabela: sessoes

 - id (pk);
 - token;
 - aplicacao_id (fk para tabela aplicacoes 1xN);
 - data_login;
```

Bom, nesse exemplo bem simples. Posso ter 1 aplicação para N sessões. Até aqui tudo bem.

O meu problema começa quando eu tento excluir uma aplicação que já tenha sessão. Logicamente, eu excluo todas as sessões daquela aplicação antes de excluir a aplicação, senão ocorreria *FK Violation*. Mas o que acontece aqui é **que mesmo eu excluindo todas as sessões referentes aquela aplicação e depois tentando excluir a aplicação ocorre um *unique key violation*!**

Oras, por que ocorreria esse unique key no delete? Faria sentido ocorrer esse problema quando eu inserisse um novo registro com nome de usuário duplicado. Mas não é esse o caso.

A exception que ocorre:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (LOADERS_SCH.UK_9F63GD4XERQ7X8MNPKSKY69V) violated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 117 more
```

O erro ocorre precisamente quando eu vou comitar a transação e não logo após o envio do delete.

**EDIÇÃO:** Estou adicionando os códigos pedidos nos comentários, mais algumas outrs coisas que talvez ajudarão na resposta.

**AplicacaoClienteVO**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "loaders_sch", name = "ws_aplicacoes_clientes")
public class AplicacaoClienteVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3401460653428856555L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq_appcliente", sequenceName = "seq_appcliente", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq_appcliente")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nome_aplicacao", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "usuario", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String usuarioAcesso;

    @Column(name = "descricao", nullable = true)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ws_app_ws", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "app_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "webservice_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<WebserviceVO> webservices;

    @Column(name = "ativo", nullable = false)
    private Boolean ativo;

    //Getters e Setters omitidos
```

**SessaoVO**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "loaders_sch", name = "ws_sessoes", indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "token"),
        @Index(columnList = "app_cliente_id")
})
public class SessaoVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7578025167356770714L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq_sessao", sequenceName = "seq_sessao", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq_sessao")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "token", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authToken;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = AplicacaoClienteVO.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_cliente_id", nullable = false)
    private AplicacaoClienteVO appCliente;

    @Column(name = "cliente_ip", nullable = false)
    private String ipCliente;

    @Column(name = "hostname", nullable = false)
    private String hostname;

    @Column(name = "porta", nullable = false)
    private String porta;

    @Column(name = "data_login", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dataHoraLogin;

    @Column(name = "data_logout", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar dataHoraLogout;

    // Getters e setters omitidos
```

Os DAOs são interfaces que extendem o JpaRepository do Spring Data. Portanto eu não tenho DAOs concretos implementados por mim. Uso somente o Spring Data. Abaixo estão as declarações dos métodos que fazem as remoções.

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from SessaoVO sessao where sessao.appCliente = ?1")
void removeSessoesByCliente(AplicacaoClienteVO appCliente);

@Modifying
@Query("delete LogAcessoVO log where log.appCliente = ?1")
void removeLogsByApoCliente(AplicacaoClienteVO appCliente);

//Para remover a aplicação é usado o método default delete() do Spring Data.
```

Abaixo é onde a regra é aplicada e onde é chamado os métodos de remoção. Lembrando que o erro ocorre sempre no commit da transação.

**AplicacaoService**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void remover(AplicacaoClienteVO appCliente) throws ServiceException {
    if (appCliente != null && appCliente.getId() != null) {
        this.sessaoDAO.delete(this.sessaoDAO.findByAppCliente(appCliente));
        this.logService.removerLogsPorAplicacao(appCliente);
        this.appClienteDAO.delete(appCliente);
    }
}
```

A constraint que da erro (UK_9F63GD4XERQ7X8MNPKSKY69V) é referente a tabela de Sessao.

Informação na tabela user_constraint (`select * from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'UK_9F63GD4XERQ7X8MNPKSKY69V'`):

```
<ROW>
    <OWNER>LOADERS_SCH</OWNER>
    <CONSTRAINT_NAME>UK_9F63GD4XERQ7X8MNPKSKY69V</CONSTRAINT_NAME>
    <CONSTRAINT_TYPE>U</CONSTRAINT_TYPE>
    <TABLE_NAME>WS_APLICACOES_CLIENTES</TABLE_NAME>
    <SEARCH_CONDITION></SEARCH_CONDITION>
    <R_OWNER></R_OWNER>
    <R_CONSTRAINT_NAME></R_CONSTRAINT_NAME>
    <DELETE_RULE></DELETE_RULE>
    <STATUS>ENABLED</STATUS>
    <DEFERRABLE>NOT DEFERRABLE</DEFERRABLE>
    <DEFERRED>IMMEDIATE</DEFERRED>
    <VALIDATED>VALIDATED</VALIDATED>
    <GENERATED>USER NAME</GENERATED>
    <BAD></BAD>
    <RELY></RELY>
    <LAST_CHANGE>05/06/2014 16:53:04</LAST_CHANGE>
    <INDEX_OWNER>LOADERS_SCH</INDEX_OWNER>
    <INDEX_NAME>UK_9F63GD4XERQ7X8MNPKSKY69V</INDEX_NAME>
    <INVALID></INVALID>
    <VIEW_RELATED></VIEW_RELATED>
</ROW>
```

Comment: Unique constraint em delete, veja : existem TRIGGERS nestas tabelas ? As constraints são deferreble ? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10003.htm

Comment: pode nos mostrar o código da DAO ou dos métodos que fazem as exclusões (tanto de aplicacao quanto de sessao)?

Comment: @Motta, não existe nenhuma trigger nesse schema de banco que estou usando. Quanto aos deferreble, não sei te dizer. Como eu verifico?

Comment: @MarceloBezerra, adicionei minhas classes e entidades na pergunta!

Comment: @Ricardo Giaviti veja na definição das constraints no BD, mas é uma hipótese fraca. Publique a definição da constraints  UK_9F63GD4XERQ7X8MNPKSKY69V)

Comment: @Motta, adicionei o select dela na user_constraints. Exportei o resultado para XML e editei na pergunta. Essa informação ajuda?

Comment: Eu sou obrigado a comitar minha transação após um delete para fazer outro delete na tabela relacionada? No meu caso, o delete na tabela Sessao precisa ser comitado antes de eu deletar o registro relacionado na tabela Aplicacao?

Comment: A Constraint é NOT DEFERRABLE que afasta minha hipótese. Tem certeza que é num DELETE ?!

Comment: Sim. Eu consegui resolver o problema. Faltava uma tabela com dados relacinado a aplicação. Fiz o delete nessa tabela e funcionou. No entanto, ainda não entendi porque o Oracle soltava erro de UK ao invés de FK.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido. Como disse, na pergunta, foi um erro idiota meu. Havia mais uma tabela que eu deveria remover uma relação que eu não sabia. Mas ainda não entendi porque o Oracle soltava  o erro de UK.